# WMI __InstanceModificationEvent filtering

Tags: c#, .net, events, wmi, monitoring

We are designing a monitoring solution for our system, and we're looking into WMI as a possible option.

In short, we want to create a generic system where it shall be possible to subscribe to multiple changes in WMI data instances. We're looking into the __InstanceModificationEvent to do this:

The following prototype code monitors all changes on any instance of notepad:

```
void StartMonitor()
{
    var query =   "SELECT * "
                + "FROM __InstanceModificationEvent "
                + "WITHIN 1 "
                + "WHERE TargetInstance Isa \"Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process\" "
                + "AND TargetInstance.Name = \"notepad\"";

    var scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\cimv2", null);
    scope.Connect();

    EventQuery qry = new EventQuery(query);

    ManagementEventWatcher w = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, qry);
    w.EventArrived += EventArrived;
    w.Start();
}

void EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    var targetInstance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];

    foreach (var p in targetInstance.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name + ":\t" + (p.Value != null ? p.Value.ToString() : "{null}"));
    }
}
```

So whenever any instance of notepad is changes, we will get an output like this (excerpt)

```
  PageFileBytes:          1499136
  PageFileBytesPeak:      1740800
  PercentPrivilegedTime:  0
  PercentProcessorTime:   0
  PercentUserTime:        0
  PoolNonpagedBytes:      7040
  PoolPagedBytes:         172856
```

This is fine, however we need to improve this a bit. For example, let's pretend we are only interested in the changes to PercentProcessorTime. With the current code, the event will be fired whenever *anything* in the object changes. This is not good enough, because we might monitor hundreds of processes across multiple computers.

Thus, we need a way to specify that we only want the event to be triggered whenever this or that property changes, not the *entire instance*

Is this possible using WMI? What's the best practice to achieve what we want?

**Edit**: I know that it is possible to write a query such as the one below and cycically poll for the value, however we were hoping to avoid that approach.

```
 SELECT PercentProcessorTime 
 FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process 
 WHERE Name = "notepad"
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid polling? You are basically polling anyway with the `WITHIN 1` clause.

Comment: System.Management already provides a generic system where you can subscribe to changes in WMI. I have to ask why you are trying to write an additional layer that must cope with any possible data requirement when one already exists. Unless you are targeting users with no WMI knowledge which by the sound of it you are not.  Whats wrong with utilising System.Management where it is required to allow your applications to request only what they need? Trying to write generic interfaces to functionality like this often end up convoluted or with lots of unnecessary data returned, or both.

Comment: @mikez that's a good point, and you might notice I am also asking about best practices.

Comment: @Ashigore the data needs to be integrated into a server system whose clients have no knowledge of WMI. Data Sources are specified at configuration time based on generic data collectors. We're making one such data collector utilizing WMI. We don't have 'users' as such

Comment: @havardhu That being the case, don't you already know what data you want to return? And therefore isn't the most efficient thing to do to run only the WMI queries required to generate that information. Since it is you, not the "clients" who will write the back-end code for the new data sources, you can utilise the WMI interface provided by the framework.

Comment: @Ashigore and how is using ManagementEventWatcher not utilizing the framework? I don't really understand where you're going with your questions.

Comment: @Ashigore yep, that's a good point, but I don't see why a generic system couldn't do that as well. My meaning of generic is that it must be possible to define the data sources at configuration time, nothing more. So subscribing to events or polling the exact values we are after both fits into my definition of a generic system. Confusion of terms, then. It's not the full story though, because we might also be interested in say 20 / 40 values of an object. In that case, what's more efficient? Polling 20 individual values or subscribing to the event? This is why I am asking about best practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__InstanceModificationEvent` has a reference to the previous instance so you might be able to compare values between the `PreviousInstance` and `TargetInstance`. For example, to filter for PercentProcessorTime changes:

```
var query =   "SELECT * "
            + "FROM __InstanceModificationEvent "
            + "WITHIN 1 "
            + "WHERE TargetInstance Isa \"Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process\" "
            + "AND TargetInstance.Name = \"notepad\" "
            + "AND PreviousInstance.PercentProcessorTime != TargetInstance.PercentProcessorTime ";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. I'm still curious to how this approach compares performance/network load wise to simply polling for the data cycically. Do you know any good articles that might cover that?

Comment: @havardhu I have not seen any good articles or recommendations about this. This suggests a time of 5 minutes, which seems absurdly long: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394527(v=vs.85).aspx